# Swift: tableView.reloadData() no data in table

Tags: swift, tableview, reloaddata

I am having trouble with the reloadData() in my table.
I have setup the table and cell, and added tables and even made a separate class for the cell in case this was the problem.
I just cannot load any data into the table..... I have read questions on here and other sites but none of the solutions are giving me solutions... 
I see that it is also a bug but it is working in a different project so its not my Xcode version. 
I have tried loading in the viewDidLoad, inside the cellForRowAt, and also using Dispatch to put it on the main thread inside and outside a function. I also tried a button in desperation but still not luck. Here is my code if you spot anything I have missed id appreciate the help.

```
//
//  VCRoster.swift
//  MC
//
//  Created by James McAdam on 08/07/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 James McAdam. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class VCRoster: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var tableViewData: [Roster] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = rosterTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rosterCell") as? rosterCell

    cell!.dateLbl.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].date
    //Have also tried ? with the cell
    cell!.messageLbl.text = tableViewData[indexPath.row].message

    tableView.reloadData()
   return cell!
}


@IBOutlet weak var rosterTable: UITableView!

@IBAction func load(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
      self.rosterTable.reloadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 //   dispatchMain().async {
 //       self.rosterTable.reloadData()
 //   }

     // self.rosterTable.reloadData()

    getDataFromServer(for: "Bx7faf08A9fYJ7bZCNMUX9EzxYN2") { (result) in
        // Check our result
        switch result {
        case .success(let results):
          //  print("Done")
            self.tableViewData = results.data
            //self.tablewView.reloadData()
            //self.rosterTable.reloadData()
        //    print(results)
        case .failure(let message):
        //    print("Error")
            print(message)
        }
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Is your view controller set as the datasource of the tableview?

Comment: Don't call `tableView.reloadData()` in `tableView(_ tableView: cellForRowAt:)`. Is `getDataFromServer()` closure in main thread? You need to call `reloadData()` there.

Comment: yes also delegate.

Comment: getDataFromServer() is in viewDidLoad.  I have left reload in the cellForRow as it was the last. thing I tried again before asking the question.

Comment: Please, edit your code to reflect something we can reproduce. (Or at least, comment out things that you tried and know do not work. I upvoted an answer that addressed an attempt at `cellForRowAt`. I shouldn't have - yet -  because that wasn't the issue.) Now, to address your actual issue? Can one assume that the issue isn't that `getDataFromServer` is called asynchronously, that is actually returns data - no error is happening - and that you tried `reloadData` after (a) `result == .success` and (b)  `let results` contains something *and* you tried `reloadData`? ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all **never, never, never** call `reloadData()` in `cellForRow`

- Make sure that datasource (and delegate) of the table view are connected to the view controller in Interface Builder
- Delete `tableView.reloadData()` in `cellForRow`
- Call `reloadData()` on the main thread in the completion handler in `viewDidLoad`

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getDataFromServer(for: "Bx7faf08A9fYJ7bZCNMUX9EzxYN2") { (result) in
        // Check our result
        switch result {
        case .success(let results):
            self.tableViewData = results.data
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.rosterTable.reloadData()
            }

        case .failure(let message):
            print(message)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does `result` return something at all?

Comment: Then the code is supposed to work. Re-check the connections of the table view and datasource

Comment: The line `self.tableViewData = results.data` should also be inside the call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @rmaddy Not necessarily. The data source array is not directly related to the UI.

Comment: Actually it is directly related since the reloading of the table is based on the state of the data source. Imagine the table is being scrolled (on the main queue of course). The table needs the current state of the data. Things can go bad if the state of the data source is modified in the background in preparation for reloading the table. There's a brief period where the state of the data source and the UI are now out of sync. I find it safer to ensure the change of the data source is made on the main queue along with the call to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set a number of sections in your case should be one section contains the number of rows then you have to set the delegate & dataSource for your tableView since you are using xib or storyboard just sign do it from there or by programmatically

```
rosterTable.delegate = self
rosterTable.dataSource = self
```

make sure that your server response with the proper data and fetch out by

```
var tableViewData: [Roster] = [] {
 didSet {
  rosterTable.reloadData()
 }
}
```

**DONT** use reloadData while rendering the cell